# Why is it that I get google search results for word definitions in 2 different languages?

Tags: google-search

This has been a recent problem I am facing when I search for a word w/ Google. I am getting my search results in 2 different languages- English and Tamil.

I'm not sure why this is occurring and I've tried to disable the personalised search results option to no avail.

[image]

What can I do about this?
Under the dropdown menu, I have tried to change it to only English, but it comes back when i reload.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.